# How to update custom properties of Word document without using Ooxml SDK?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I am trying to **change the value of a custom property of a Package** (Word or Excel documents) using plain C# and XLinq instead of Ooxml SDK.  However, it corrupts the file and does not reflect the change in the package.

Can someone please suggest what is incorrect here?

```
        Package package = null;
        try
        {
            package = Package.Open("NewCustomProp.docx", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            foreach (var packagePart in package.GetParts())
            {
                if (packagePart.ContentType == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.custom-properties+xml")
                {
                    var packageStream = packagePart.GetStream(FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(packageStream))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            string ns = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/custom-properties";
                            XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
                            var properties = xDocument.Descendants(XName.Get("property", ns)).Where(x => x.Attribute(XName.Get("name")).Value == "NewCustomProp").ToList();
                            if (properties.Count > 0)
                            {
                                foreach (var currentProperty in properties)
                                {
                                    var valueNode = currentProperty.Descendants().First();
                                    valueNode.Value = "This is new value of Custom Property";
                                }

                                StringBuilder innerXmlSB = new StringBuilder();
                                xDocument.Nodes().ToList().ForEach(node => innerXmlSB.Append(node.ToString()));
                                string innerXml = innerXmlSB.ToString();
                                byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(innerXml);
                                packageStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                                //tried this as well
                                //xDocument.Save(packageStream);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            package.Flush();
        }
        finally
        {
            package.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, don't know much about C#, but this is how it is done in VB.NET with Linq, XML Literals and IO.Packaging (i.e. no SDK required).

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Packaging
Imports <xmlns:vt="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/docPropsVTypes">
Imports System.Xml

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim docFilePath = "C:\Users\you\Documents\Doc2.docx"
        Using presentationPackage As Package = Package.Open(docFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
            Dim uriCustom = New Uri("/docProps/custom.xml", UriKind.Relative)
            Dim customPart = presentationPackage.GetPart(uriCustom)
            Dim customStream = New StreamReader(customPart.GetStream)

            Dim custom = XDocument.Load(customStream)
            Dim customProperties = custom.Root.Elements.<vt:lpwstr>

            For Each prop In customProperties
                prop.Value = "My New Custom Value"
            Next

            Using xw As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(customPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                custom.Save(xw)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub

End Module
```

Note that this - `<vt:lpwstr>` -is for the "Text" type of custom property. It just directly changes values. If you want query exact customer properties or change things like the custom property's name or work with a different types, you'll have to change some things around in the code below.